# Java: What is the easiest way to get entire URL except last part?

Tags: java

consider the url is

```
http://www.google.com/a/b/myendpoint
```

All I want is the following

```
http://www.google.com/a/b/
```

One approach is to split the String url and join all the components except last one.

I am thinking if there could be a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29):

```
url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

---

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/a/b/myendpoint";
System.out.println(url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

```
http://www.google.com/a/b/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either of the following both are same

```
pathofURL = url.subString(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

or
**if it has no Query**

```
pathofURL = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority() + url.getPath();
pathofURL = pathofURL.subString(0, pathofURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

It has Query alone

```
pathofURL = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority() + url.getPath();
```

It has Query and Reference

```
pathofURL = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getAuthority() + url.getFile();
```

Hope it helps, check the URL and use either of the above.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest uses the URI.resolve method: `url.toURI().resolve("").toURL()`.
*(You could start immediately with URIs.)*

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google/intl/eo/index.html");
URL url2 = url.toURI().resolve("favicon.ico").toURL(); // Or "" for the question.
System.out.println("url2: " + url2.toExternalForm());

// url2: http://www.google/intl/eo/favicon.ico
```